# Can we connect to a socket using fetch API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, fetch-api

I've hosted **socket.io** based web API and I wish to access it using a static web page. Can we use **socket.io-client** without server (static webpage) or use fetch method to communicate with the web API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use socket.io with your static webpage.

from their docs
https://socket.io/docs/

**Client side code**

```
const socket = io('ws://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connect', () => {
  // either with send()
  socket.send('Hello!');

  // or with emit() and custom event names
  socket.emit('salutations', 'Hello!', { 'mr': 'john' }, Uint8Array.from([1, 2, 3, 4]));
});

// handle the event sent with socket.send()
socket.on('message', data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

You'll need to make sure you add it to your html too like so

```
    <script src="localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

replace `localhost:3000` with the address of your server

Answer (score 0):

You can even use the newly added [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) API.
In case you don't want to add external libraries to your website for some reason